# R count the number of words starts with given letter in a phrase

Tags: r, string

i would like to get the count times that in a given string a word start with the letter given.

For example, in that phrase: "that pattern is great but pigs likes milk"
if i want to find the number of words starting with "g" there is only 1 "great", but right now i get 2 "great" and "pigs".

this is the code i use:

```
x <- "that pattern is great but pogintless"
sapply(regmatches(x, gregexpr("g", x)), length)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need either a space or word boundary to avoid th letter from matching to characters other than the start of the word.  In addition, it may be better to use `ignore.case = TRUE` as some words may begin with uppercase

```
lengths(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\bg", x, ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

The above can be wrapped as a function

```
fLength <- function(str1, pat){
       lengths(regmatches(str1, gregexpr(paste0("\\b", pat), str1, ignore.case = TRUE)))
 }

fLength(x, "g")
#[1] 1
```

Comment: I believe the pattern `"^g|\\bg"` would be better, it gets the case where `g` is the first charcter of the string.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  It would pick up both `gregexpr("\\bg", "good evening good bye")#[[1]]
[1]  1 14`
`

Comment: Right, somehow I messed up my test. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  It's good that brought that up in case somebody benefits from that discussion.  Thanks

Comment: how would it be calling a function and give the letter i want to look for?

Comment: @SergioSuarez  Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with stringr library

```
library(stringr)
str_count(str_split(x," "),"\\bg")
```